# Phonegap app to send data via wifi

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I have an idea about an app. This app will simply send data from my ipad to iphone via wifi. My question is that is it possible to make app that sends data through wifi using **phonegap**?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your devices are on the same WiFi network, this is achievable.  If there is no WiFi AP available, you're looking at more difficulty because iOS devices cannot create ad-hoc networks.

Take a look at [this plugin](http://rossmartindev.blogspot.com/2012/12/my-phonegap-bonjour-plugin-it-can.html), which uses Bonjour to discover the IP address of other devices running your app, and can then establish a TCP connection between the devices.